# Cannot install package in npm: auth is required

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, mern, npm-publish

I cloned a fullstack MERN (Typescript) project from GitHub and when I was checking out the code on VS code I noticed there were errors everywhere for packages as if they weren't installed and when i want to install them I just can't and would get the following error for instance installing express with (npm install express) or any other package:

```
npm WARN idealTree Removing dependencies.@types/node in favor of devDependencies.@types/node
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@designed-and-developed%2feslint-config-prettier-typescript-react - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@designed-and-developed/eslint-config-prettier-typescript-react@^1.0.9' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

When I searched it up I found out that it has something to do with having an npm account and signing in to it, but I don't want any of that, I just want to be able to run the website locally while avoiding the errors that I have been getting regarding the uninstalled packages. How can I do that?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "lofi-env",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/ni-xon/lofi-env.git",
  "author": "ni-xon <nixonuch_@outlook.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon --config nodemon.json backend/server.ts",
    "client": "yarn --cwd frontend start",
    "start": "yarn server",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@designed-and-developed/eslint-config-prettier-typescript-react": "^1.0.9",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  }
}
```

In fact, I would get this error whenever I call NPM (even when I do NPM install!)

Thank you.

Comment: What's the package you're actually trying to install in the first place? I mean, express on its own doesn't seem to have such a dependency.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I edited my question and i added my json file as well

Comment: @raina77ow is right, do you really need this package ? Please post the github link so we can also try

Comment: Yeah, i mean its part of the code. This is the github link https://github.com/ni-xon/lofi-env#lofi-env.

Comment: @l-_-l IDK if you tried to clone it but the mess is in the backend side. I just cant run it. The front end is fine tho

Comment: "
> lofi-env@1.0.0 start
> yarn server

00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server'"  is what i get when running npm start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246119/discussion-between-william-and-l-l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your .npmrc :

```
registry=https://registry.yarnpkg.com/
@designed-and-developed:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
always-auth=true
```

There's no NPM Token, so you can't authenticate to Github Packages in order to fetch your package. Obtain one, put it inside the braces and try again :)

Cheers

Comment: I just created a token but i coudnt find the lines of code that you mentioned in your answer!. Am I supposed to copy them and paste them in yarn.lock file or are they there somewhere in the code?

Comment: The file is named .npmrc

Comment: hmmm in which dir exactly? I cant find it.

Maybe I should create one?

Comment: It's literally located at the root of your project: /lofi-env/.npmrc

If it's not present create it yes

Comment: My bad it seemed like i deleted it by mistake somehow